# How to find pseudoinverse Moore–Penrose matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I have $\begin{align}
         A &= \begin{bmatrix}
           2 \\             
           3 \\
           \vdots \\
           \sqrt{5n-1}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}             $*$\begin{align} \begin{bmatrix} -1& 1 & ... & (-1)^n \end{bmatrix}^* \end{align}$

And I want to compute Moore–Penrose inverse matrix of A. That is $A^+$.

My attempts: definition with limits $A^+ = \lim_{\delta \to +0} (A^* A + \delta I)^{-1} A^*$. This doesn't work because I have no idea in computing inverse matrix with parameter and $A^*A$ is not invertible. Also I can say that $A$  is not invertible, so I can't consider that $A^+=A^{-1}$.

Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: This is a rank one matrix. $(xy^\ast)^+=\frac{yx^\ast}{\|x\|^2\|y\|^2}$. That is, $A^+=A^\ast/\|A\|_F^2$.

Comment: @user1551 I can't understand first equality. Could you please explain it?

Comment: Forget the limiting definition. Check the four defining properties of M-P inverse. Or use SVD.

Comment: @user1551 thank you very much!